# PHP: Alternating between text display

Tags: php

I'm using the below PHP code to do a A/B split. I am using the seconds (odd vs even) to trigger the alternate text display. Im looking for another way to evenly alternate text display. Any other methods I could use?

```
<?php // A/B Testing ... 
if(fmod(date('s'),'2')=='1') {$hosp_btn='game1'; $hosp_txt='game2';}
   else {$hosp_btn='contact-us'; $hosp_txt='Contact Us';}
?>

<button onClick="ga('send', 'event', 'GameSet', 'game-click', '<?php echo $hosp_btn; ?>');" id="dropdown_button" type="button" href="" class="form-button-view">
                        <?php echo $hosp_txt; ?>
</button>
```

Comment: http://php.net/manual/en/function.rand.php

Comment: What about `rand(0,1)`?

Comment: If you use a random number, use mt_rand() (http://php.net/manual/en/function.mt-rand.php)

Comment: "to **evening** alternate" what does that mean?

Comment: Using your current method, I would recommend improving the `fmod()` expression just as `time() % 2 == 1` since `time()` returns an integer representing seconds.  There's no need to involve string operations in `date()`

Comment: Why "`fmod(date('s'),'2')=='1'`"? `time() % 2` is more than enough, does the exact same thing and runs like the wind.

Comment: @axiac That's exactly what the previous comment says.

Comment: @DigitalChris sorry typo, i've corrected.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use rand() or mt_rand().
mt_rand generates a better random value.

[rand($min, $max)](http://php.net/manual/en/function.rand.php)

[mt_rand($min, $max)](http://php.net/manual/en/function.mt-rand.php)

```
<?php 
if(mt_rand(0,1)=='1') {
    $hosp_btn='game1'; 
    $hosp_txt='game2';
}else{
    $hosp_btn='contact-us'; 
    $hosp_txt='Contact Us';}
?>

<button onClick="ga('send', 'event', 'GameSet', 'game-click', '<?php echo $hosp_btn; ?>');" id="dropdown_button" type="button" href="" class="form-button-view">
    <?php echo $hosp_txt; ?>
</button>
```

Comment: Use `mt_rand`, not `rand`.